XSD: Change element type in child xsd where the type is a custom created type
I want to change the type of an element that is inherited from a parent xsd in another xsd
Here is a section of the "parent" xsd with the types
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:simpleType name="Str30m1">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="Str20">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="Data">
    <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LINE1" type="Str30m1" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="LINE2" type="Str20" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="LINE3" type="Str20" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Common_dataType">
<xs:element name="Details">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>   
    <xs:element name="Values" type="Data"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>

I'd like to change the type for LINE2 to be Str30m1 but can't seem to get it working. I assume it has to do with the fact that these are local (is that the right word in this context?) and is confusing things
So far, in the "child" xsd I have tried something like
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="parent.xsd">
    <xs:complexType name="Data">
    <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="Data">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="LINE2" type="Str30m1" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
<xs:element name="Common_Data" type="Common_dataType"/>
</xs:schema>

But when I try to validate this I get an error
cos-element-consistent: Error for type 'Data'. Multiple elements with name 'LINE2', with different types, appear in the model group.
Using restriction instead of extension I get
rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles
I'm guessing I am missing something or doing something wrong here but I am not sure and any input would be appreciated

The xs:redefine mechanism can't be used to make arbitrary changes to a schema, like changing the type of an element to a completely unrelated type. Even where it can be used, it has grave problems because it's often unclear exactly what the scope of the change is.
I would suggest writing an XSLT transformation to transform this schema to a different schema.
